# exslt features not working in ruby-xslt gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xslt, rubygems, bundler

I have a Rails app and use Bundler to manage gems.
I use the ruby-xslt gem for XSLT transformations.
The gem is not recognizing exslt features like node-set().

Here’s the stylesheet I’ve been testing with

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.1" 
        xmlns="http://max.gov" 
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
        xmlns:pre="http://max.gov"
        xmlns:exslt="http://exslt.org/common">
        <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

        <!--The fabricated xml I want to access with exslt:node-set()-->
        <xsl:variable name="PRE">
                    <root>
                                <item/>
                                <item/>
                    </root>
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:template match="/">
                    <results>
                                <run1 name="exslt:node-set($PRE)//pre:item">
                                            <results>
                                            <xsl:for-each select="exslt:node-set($PRE)//pre:item">
                                                        <success position="{position()}"/>
                                            </xsl:for-each>
                                            </results>
                                </run1>
                                <run2 name="exslt:node-set($PRE)//pre:item">
                                            <results>
                                            <xsl:for-each select="exslt:node-set($PRE)//pre:item">
                                                        <success position="{position()}"/>
                                            </xsl:for-each>
                                            </results>
                                </run2>
                    </results>
        </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here’s output I get when using XML::XSLT in our app:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<results xmlns="http://max.gov" xmlns:pre="http://max.gov" xmlns:exslt="http://exslt.org/common">
   <run1 name="exslt:node-set($PRE)//pre:item">
    <results/>
  </run1>
</results>
```

(Note that not only did the node-set function not work, the  element got skipped altogether.)
The code is basically this:

```
xslt = XML::XSLT.new()
xslt.xml = @xml         # @xml string
xslt.xsl = @record.xslt # xslt is stored in db
result = xslt.serve
render :xml => result
```

Here’s the expected output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <results xmlns="http://max.gov" xmlns:pre="http://max.gov" xmlns:exslt="http://exslt.org/common">
       <run1 name="exslt:node-set($PRE)//pre:item">
          <results>
             <success position="1"/>
             <success position="2"/>
          </results>
       </run1>
       <run2 name="exslt:node-set($PRE)//pre:item">
           <results>
             <success position="1"/>
             <success position="2"/>
           </results>
       </run2>
</results>
```

I get this correct result when doing any of the following…

- Run xsltproc from command line
- Run the following in the Rails console

> > xslt = XML::XSLT.new
> >     xslt.xml = File.read('data.xml')
> >     xslt.xsl = File.read('test.xsl')
> >     xslt.serve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up replacing ruby-xslt with Nokogiri and this fixed our problems